# Upload image to Mysql server using php and android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I was trying to build a registration page where the users register their name and other details. The details entered was able to be uploaded to my database. But I was unable to upload image to the database.

php code

```
 <?php


$hostname = "localhost";
//Define your database username here.
$username = "Droidparkz";
//Define your database password here.
$password = "***********";
//Define your database name here.
$dbname = "KEA";

$con = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$dbname);

 $Image = $_POST['Image'];

 $id = 0;

 $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
 $id = $row['id'];
 }

 $path = "http://droidparkz.in/kea/profileimages/images/$id.png";

 $sql = "INSERT INTO User_details (IMAGE) VALUES ('$path')";

 if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
 file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
 echo "Successfully Uploaded";
 }

 mysqli_close($con);
```

Java code

RequestHandler.Java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;


public class RequestHandler {

    public String sendGetRequest(String uri) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(uri);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String result;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while((result = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(result);
            }

            return sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,
                                  HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

        URL url;
        String response = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                response = br.readLine();
            } else {
                response = "Error Registering";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Userimage.Java

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Userimage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button buttonUpload;

    private CircularImageView circularImageView;

    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Uri filePath;

    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

    public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://droidparkz.in/kea/profileimages/imageuplod.php";
    public static final String UPLOAD_KEY = "image";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_userimage);

        circularImageView =  (CircularImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_profile);
        buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadimagebutton);

        circularImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                circularImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }

    private void uploadImage(){
        class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Bitmap,Void,String> {

            ProgressDialog loading;
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(Userimage.this, "Uploading Image", "Please wait...",true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
                Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
                String uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmap);

                HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put(UPLOAD_KEY, uploadImage);

                String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL,data);

                return result;
            }
        }

        UploadImage ui = new UploadImage();
        ui.execute(bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == circularImageView) {
            showFileChooser();
        }
        if(v == buttonUpload){
            uploadImage();
        }
    }
}
```

The codes are done by referring some online tutorials and other places. I am not sure about how much the codes are correct. It will be a great help if you provide with single php code for both uploading image and text.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569).

Comment: Your `$path`-variable is an absolute URL. You can't use that with `file_put_contents()`. You need to give that function a file system path. Also, when you call the first `$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);`, you haven't defined `$sql` yet. You should really check your web servers error log.

Comment: There is a bunch of code there, I doubt anyone will read the whole posted code. Can't you just show us the **relevants** parts that causes you issues?

Comment: `$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);` the variable `$sql` isn't yet defined.

Comment: Another thing, you define: `UPLOAD_KEY = "image";` but you are trying to fetch `$_POST['Image']` in PHP. Parameter names are case sensitive so `image != Image`. I would recommend that you write your code step by step. Start with just sending a POST request. Then add some parameters and see if you get that working. Then you can add on more and more as you test it. That will most likely make it easier to learn how to do it. Right now, you have a bunch of code that aren't correct, which makes it much harder to debug and find help.